# A bug in a function which takes an ENUM arguments In C

Tags: c, enums

I am currently working on a C console game to learn C programming. I have 3 .c files(player.c game.c board.c) and 3 .h files(player.h, game.h,board.h). And game.h include board.h and player.h, board.h include player.h.

In player.h, i have something below.

```
typedef enum direction
{
  NORTH,
  EAST,
  SOUTH,
  WEST
} Direction;

typedef struct player
{
  Position position;
  Direction direction;
} Player;

void displayDirection(Direction direction);
void init(Player * player,Direction direction);
```

So in this console game, i need print arrow in different direction(NORTH, WEST,EAST,SOUTH), i have modify the function displayDirection like this.

```
if(direction==NORTH){
    printf("%s|",DIRECTION_ARROW_OUTPUT_NORTH);
//I already define DIRECTION_ARROW_OUTPUT_NORTH in my .h file.
}
else if(direction==EAST){
    printf("%s|",DIRECTION_ARROW_OUTPUT_EAST);
}
else if(direction==SOUTH){
    printf("%s|",DIRECTION_ARROW_OUTPUT_SOUTH);
}
else if(direction==WEST){
    printf("%s|",DIRECTION_ARROW_OUTPUT_WEST);
}
```

for init()function

```
player->direction=direction;
```

In board.c file, i have a function to call displayDirection();

```
void displayBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], Player * player)
{
   for(row=0;row<BOARD_HEIGHT;row++){

    for(col=0;col<BOARD_WIDTH;col++){
      if(board[row][col]==PLAYER){
            displayDirection(player->direction);

        }}
   printf("\n");
}
```

Finally, in my game.c file.I am using scanf to read input(direction) from user,and display it.

```
Player player;
Direction d;
scanf("%u",&d);
init(&player,d);
displayBoard(board,&player);
```

I have tested it, however everytime i enter the direction(such as WEST), it only give me NORTH direction.I don't know where is the problem, i feel it is my enum problem, i have searched enum type online, still cannot solve the problem. Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: An `enum` is not an `unsigned int`

Comment: And thus `scanf("%u",&d);` doesn't make sense.

Comment: And even if it did work (e.g. if you read into an `unsigned int`), you would have to type the number and not the name (`WEST`).

Comment: What's the return value from `scanf()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause of problem**
In line `scanf("%u",&d);` you are assuming `enum` type and `unsigned int` types are interchangeable which is not true.

**Possible fix**
Make a helper function to take the direction input. Here you can read user input as an `int` or `c string` and can map it to `enum` type.

```
Direction getDirection(void) {
  int d = 0;
  static const Direction mapping[] = {NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST};
  do {
    if(0 != d) fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "***ERROR*** Bad input, ignored");
    printf("Enter direction 0:N, 1:E, 2:S, 3:W\n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
  } while(d < 0 || d > 3);
  return mapping[d];
}
```

And later:

```
Direction d = getDirection();
```